# Is this the best approach to parsing with LXML?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, lxml

I'm new to LXML, and parsing XML documents in general. I have written a small section of code that appears to do what I need it too do, but it feels like I have overly complicated it. Is there any way I can simplify this?

> METHOD:

```
def importFromXML(self, filename):
    tree = etree.parse(filename)
    for child in tree.getroot():
        if child.tag != 'SLOT':
            print('Tag:', child.tag, ', Text', child.text)
        elif child.tag == 'SLOT':
            for slot, index in child.items():
                for attribute in child:
                    print('Slot Number =', index, ', Tag:', attribute.tag, ', Value:', attribute.text)
```

> XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Item>
<ActiveState>drop</ActiveState>
<Location>Left Wrist</Location>
<Realm>All</Realm>
<ItemName>Band of the Dream Conqueror</ItemName>
<ItemQuality>100</ItemQuality>
<Equipped>1</Equipped>
<Level>50</Level>
<TYPE>Wrist</TYPE>
<SOURCE>Drop</SOURCE>
<DBSOURCE>kscraft</DBSOURCE>
<SLOT Number="0">
    <Type>Resist</Type>
    <Effect>Crush</Effect>
    <Amount>6</Amount>
</SLOT>
<SLOT Number="1">
    <Type>Resist</Type>
    <Effect>Thrust</Effect>
    <Amount>6</Amount>
</SLOT>
<SLOT Number="2">
    <Type>Resist</Type>
    <Effect>Slash</Effect>
        <Amount>6</Amount>
</SLOT>
</Item>
```

I just want to make sure I'm doing this right. I'm using Python 3.x

Comment: So your target is to print it right? For this specific case, I don't believe there would be a better way.

Comment: For right now I'm just printing to make sure I can pull the data fields that I need before proceeding with what to do with the data.

Comment: XPath is an exellent option

Comment: This depends on what you want to do. From my knowledge, there is not better way to do that, except maybe recursion, or putting some parts in other functions.

Comment: *I  just want to make sure I'm doing this right* ... if code renders your desire output it is right. Now, efficiency, optimization, best practices is a different question and should be asked on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as SO is for code that errs out or yields undesired results.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you have to use lxml? I would highly recommend using BeautifulSoup https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/. You can just use the html parser and it's a way nicer API.

Comment: @Stats4224 I have used BS4 before, and while I agree, most of my XML output is already written in LXML, so I'm trying not to introduce things that do essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Parfait I was not aware of CodeReview, and wasn't sure if this was the right place. I will move the question over there. Thank you.

Comment: Shameless plug but not too long ago I optimized a CodeReviewer's `lxml` code to avoid multiple `for` loops, recommending `xpath`. See [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/185915/112275). Sadly our OP seemed to disappear to other side of Internet! On SO posters are more responsive.

Comment: @Parfait I'm still learning, so I try to engage past the basic Q/A for my own educational reasons. Thank you for the suggestion. I reposted this on CodeReview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing to criticise about your parsing. In particular, it's very readable, and easy to understand. However, I would suggest a minor adjustment to the `if` statement.

- Writing it in this way avoids the use of a `not`, and `not` adds one additional barrier to understanding in code as in natural language.
- I've discarded an `elif` for a plain `else`.

---

```
if child.tag == 'SLOT':
    for slot, index in child.items():
        for attribute in child:
            print('Slot Number =', index, ', Tag:', attribute.tag, ', Value:', attribute.text)
else:
    print('Tag:', child.tag, ', Text', child.text)
```